# Insert into Table Variable getting Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
        DECLARE @myTemp TABLE (Item Varchar(10) Not Null,
                            [Description    Varchar(30) Not Null,
                            LonDescription  Varchar(50),
                            [Level]         Char(1),
                            LevelDesc       Varchar(15),
                            GID             Varchar(16),
                            [Min]           Int,
                            [Max]           Int,
                            QTY             Int,
                            QoO             Int)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cAreaLocationItems Into @citem,@cDesc,@cLDesc,@cLVL,@cLVLDesc,@cGID,@cMin,@cMax,@cqty
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 -- We're out of items
            BREAK
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        Begin
            Declare @QoO    Int

            SELECT      @QoO = SUM(QtyReqd - QtyActual) 
            FROM        abc.tblorders
            WHERE     (ItemNumber = @cItem) AND (Status <> '4') And 
                            Bin = @Location 
            GROUP BY    ItemNumber, UPC, [Level], Description, Bin
            If @QoO = Null
                Set @QoO = 0

            Insert into @myTemp values(@cItem,@cDesc,@cLDesc,@clvl,@cLVLDesc,@cGid,@cMin,@cMax,@cQTy,@QoO)

            FETCH NEXT FROM cAreaLocationItems Into @citem,@cDesc,@cLDesc,@cLVL,@cLVLDesc,@cGID,@cMin,@cMax,@cqty
        end
```

Get the error executed stored procedure on the insert into @myTemp table variable defined above. Table says 10 columns and insert has ten values. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the column names in the insert query like this:

```
Insert into @myTemp (Item Varchar,[Description,LonDescription,Level],LevelDesc,GID,[Min],[Max],QTY,QoO) values(@cItem,@cDesc,@cLDesc,@clvl,@cLVLDesc,@cGid,@cMin,@cMax,@cQTy,@QoO)
```

It helps you to avoid error when you add new column into the table

Comment: Thanks but in looking at your suggestion I relooked at my table definition and notice I had bracket in beginning of description [ without a ] at the end